# PHP - foreach function with array

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach, while-loop

Hi I have an error when I call a function.

> "Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\posts.php
>   on line 28
>   2"

function:

```
function get_short_posts() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 0, 5";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $timestamp = new DateTime($row['date']);
        return array (
            "id" => $row['id'],
            "title" => $row['title'],
            "content" => $row['content'],
            "author" => $row['author'],
            "date" => $timestamp->format('d-m-Y'),
            "time" => $timestamp->format('H:i')
        );
    }
```

Call:

```
require_once "functions.php";
    $_posts = get_short_posts();
    foreach($_posts as $_post) {
        echo $_post['id'];
    }
```

Comment: Try doing `die(var_dump($row));` in your while loop. This will halt all other execution, and display the error on screen.

Comment: You know you return after the first iteration in the get_short_posts function right, so the foreach will not work as expected.

Comment: Show your table columns names, please. Maybe column "id" called "Id" or "ID"?

Comment: Also, try: `$result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you return after the first iteration in the get_short_posts function right, so the foreach will not work as expected.

## Try:

```
<?php 
function get_short_posts() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 0, 5";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $return = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $timestamp = new DateTime($row['date']);
        $return[] = array (
            "id" => $row['id'],
            "title" => $row['title'],
            "content" => $row['content'],
            "author" => $row['author'],
            "date" => $timestamp->format('d-m-Y'),
            "time" => $timestamp->format('H:i')
        );
    }
    return $return;
}
?>

<?php 
require_once "functions.php";

foreach(get_short_posts() as $_post) {
    echo $_post['id'];
}
?>
```

Also, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_short_posts() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 0, 5";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $timestamp = new DateTime($row['date']);
        $data [] = array (
            "id" => $row['id'],
            "title" => $row['title'],
            "content" => $row['content'],
            "author" => $row['author'],
            "date" => $timestamp->format('d-m-Y'),
            "time" => $timestamp->format('H:i')
        );

    }
    return $data;
    }
```

you return data, so the loop stops, save your data in a array and return that array like abive code

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong it should be as below, assuming the query is returning data as mentioned.

```
function get_short_posts() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 0, 5";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = array();
    $return_data = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $timestamp = new DateTime($row['date']);
        $data = array (
            "id" => $row['id'],
            "title" => $row['title'],
            "content" => $row['content'],
            "author" => $row['author'],
            "date" => $timestamp->format('d-m-Y'),
            "time" => $timestamp->format('H:i')
        );
        $return_data[] = $data;
    }
    return $return_data ;

}


require_once "functions.php";
    $posts = get_short_posts();
    foreach($posts as $key=>$val) {
        echo $val['id'];
    }
```